Help with CFA fit indices and interpretation
First post on here, so apologies in advance if it's not formatted correctly.
For context, I recruited a total of 227 participants, which I randomly split in two. The first half was used for an EFA and the second half for a CFA. I've just ran the CFA, informed by the outcome of the earlier EFA and I'm a little puzzled by the output. As I have a relatively small sample size (n = 113 for the CFA) and non-normal data on 5-point Likert scales (ordinal), I am using DWLS.
Specifically it's the RMSEAs confidence intervals I'm worried about. I don't know, the indices look too good to be true...
Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

JASP OUTPUT

FIT INDICES-
Chi-Squared Test:
X2 = 16.43, df = 34, p = 1.00
CFI = 1.00
TLI = 1.01
RMSEA = 0.00
RMSEA 90% CI lower bound = 0.00
RMSEA 90% CI upper bound = 0.00
RMSEA p-value = 1.00
SRMR = 0.04

FACTOR LOADINGS
Factor 1-
Item 1: 0.71
Item 2: 0.81
Item 3: 0.86
Item 4: 0.81
Item 5: 0.79
Factor 2-
Item 1: 0.82
Item 2: 0.83
Item 3: 0.80
Item 4: 0.76
Item 5: 0.77
Is it strange that all their standard errors are 0.03?
I can also provide other output if that helps too.
Thanks!
